# Provider authorities error when publish update to Play Market

Tags: google-play, provider

I try to upload a new version to Play Market, but meet below error. The sharp are my own package name.
Then I rollback all my changes, there is still such a problem. I upload it in App bundles format.

*Remove conflicts from the manifest before uploading. The following content provider authorities are in use by other developers: com.###.fileprovider, com.###.firebaseinitprovider, com.###.mobileadsinitprovider.*

[image]

Comment: I'm having the same issue with fileprovider. Figure it out yet?

Comment: @ShrimpCrackers For fileprovider issue, you can fix it in AndroidManifest.xml. Change the fileprovider of android:authorities="com.###.fileprovider" to provider.

Comment: I add a provider in AndroidManifest.xml to force remove mobileadsinitprovider,there is no problem now. But I don't know whether it's OK, or it will affect Admob Ad not not.<provider
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.ads.MobileAdsInitProvider"
            android:authorities="${applicationId}.mobileadsinitprovider"
            tools:node="remove" />

Comment: Same issue here, @Dongfu He How did you solved the problems, force remove node is not a good idea, as mobileadsinitprovider and firebaseinitprovider are from google's Admob SDK and Firebase SDK.

Comment: I published a version to force remove node. Then update a new version without it, it seems OK, no usch issue anymore.